# Increment a value in a sql database when a pdf link is downloaded on a webpage

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, web

I'm creating an eBook account on my website: where customers can have a library of ebooks and every time an eBook is downloaded, I need to add 1 to the database for the client to be able to see the number of downloads. I can not figure out the line of code I would need for this and I have done research but nothing can help with this specific query. This is what I have so far, which pulls the information from a sql table and display in html table:

```
                    <p>List of Publications</p>
                    <?php
```

//connect
    $query = "SELECT * FROM AccountTest";

```
$query = mysql_query($query);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

        ?>
    <table style="width: 80%; border:2px #be9c81 dashed; padding:10px 10px 10px 10px"align="center" >
        <tr>    

            <td>            <?php if ($numrows > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
    ?>


            <a href="<?php echo $row['Link']; ?>" target="_blank">
            <img style="padding:20px 20px 20px 20px" alt=""  src="<?php echo $row['Image'];  ?>" /></a> <?php
    }

} else 

echo "Wrong Query";
```

?>

```
        </tr>
```

Comment: Where is your EXACT problem?

Comment: Actually your files should be saved out of your webroot and you should access it through an handler script. In this script you will of course return the file, but not before having checked access rights for current user, and logged download/buy from this user.

Comment: My EXACT problem is I have no idea how to go about coding a script to add 1 to the database when the link is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JQuery

ebookDownloads.php

```
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="javascript/text">
// JavaScript Document
function Downloaded(id) {
    var data = {'id':id};
    $.post( "downloaded.php", data);
}
</script>
</head>

<p>List of Publications</p>

<?php
//connect $query = "SELECT * FROM AccountTest";
$query = mysql_query($query);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
?>
<table style="width: 80%; border:2px #be9c81 dashed; padding:10px 10px 10px 10px"align="center" >
    <tr>
<?php 
if ($numrows > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    ?>    
    <td><a href="<?php echo $row['Link']; ?>" onclick="Downloaded(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>);" target="_blank"><img style="padding:20px 20px 20px 20px" alt=""  src="<?php echo $row['Image'];  ?>" /></a></td>
    <?php
    }
} else {
    echo "Wrong Query";
}
?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

downloaded.php

```
if(isset($_POST['id']) && is_numeric($_POST['id'])) {
    $sql = "UPDATE table SET downloaded=downloaded+1 WHERE id = $_POST['id']";
}
```

EDIT: I have not tested this code. Also the user might not have javascript enabled in which case it wouldn't count the download, so if you need to count the downloads (e.g they pay for so many) you could make sure they have javascript enabled before showing the downloads.

Update: another method using a new tab and PHP to record the download then present it

```
<p>List of Publications</p>

<?php
//connect $query = "SELECT * FROM AccountTest";
$query = mysql_query($query);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
?>
<table style="width: 80%; border:2px #be9c81 dashed; padding:10px 10px 10px 10px"align="center" >
    <tr>
<?php 
if ($numrows > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    ?>    
    <td><a href="download.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" target="_blank"><img style="padding:20px 20px 20px 20px" alt=""  src="<?php echo $row['Image'];  ?>" /></a></td>
    <?php
    }
} else {
    echo "Wrong Query";
}
?>
    </tr>
</table>

<?php
######## download.php #######################
if(isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ebooks WHERE id = $_GET['id']";
    $query = mysql_query($query);
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if ($numrows > 0) {
        $sql = "UPDATE table SET downloaded=downloaded+1 WHERE id = $_POST['id']"; // update downloaded
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
            header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename='.$row['name'].'pdf');
            readfile($row['link']); // should be an absolute path
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your help, unfortunately I cannot get your method to work. And I need the system to update the database and then I will create a separate page to display the current downloads per ebook. The onclick function directs the user to that page which I don't want. But thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I have added another method which should work. You click the link and it will open a new tab which will add to the download database then force the download of the clicked PDF.

"I need the system to update the database and then I will create a separate page to display the current downloads" - this method works almost opposite :/ present the downloads and then update the database on download.